# Is there a way to use 'and' in a django template to check 2 variables?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to check if two variables are equal to none and if so, display something, but I am not sure how to use an and in the template and check if both variables are `None`.

HTML:

```
{% if post.company_title and post.company_image %}
    <img class="company_image" src="{{ post.company_image.url }}" alt="{{ post.company.url }}">
{% elif post.company_title == "" %}
    <img class="company_image" src="{{ post.company_image.url }}" alt="{{ post.company.url }}">
{% elif post.company_image == "" %}
    <p>{{ post.company_title }}</p>
{% elif not post.company_title and not post.company_image %}
<!-- This does not work when both fields are false aside from that -->
<!-- It all works -->
    <p>nooo</p>
{% endif %}
```

- The first if checks if both have a value.
- The first else if checks if one doesn't have a value
- The second else if checks if one doesn't have a value
- The last else if should check if they both do not have values.

If anyone knows how to check to variables if they are equal to none that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `variable is None`.
`None`, `True` and `False` are available in Django templates

Comment: I have just tried that, but I am not sure if I am using the and properly